# AlertDialog with an editText in Android

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

I need to put in an editText inside of an alertDialog. From what I can understand, from [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AlertDialog), I need to create a custom dialog. Is that really the only way to put an editText in a alertDialog? I don't want to take make steps than needed to complete a simple task. It should like this in the end:

```
------------------------
-Please enter your name-
- [                   ]-
-         (Save)       -
------------------------
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is the proper (and potentially only) way to do this at present.

Something like this:

```
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Please enter your name")
    .setView(input) // Use our EditText
    .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // Save value of `input.getText()`
        }
    }).show();
```

This is a customized version of the code from [this blog](http://www.androidsnippets.com/prompt-user-input-with-an-alertdialog) that I use from time to time.

Answer (score 2):

```
AlertDialog.Builder alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

alert.setTitle("Title");
alert.setMessage("Message");

// Set an EditText view to get user input 
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
alert.setView(input);
```

This way you don't have to create a new custom dialogue.

Answer (score 1):

You can not only put EditText, but any thing you want. Just create an XML layout for what ever you want to put and then use it as is shown in the link :-

[how to get customized alert dialog , like the one shown in image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12721828/how-to-get-customized-alert-dialog-like-the-one-shown-in-image/12721965#12721965)

Refer the answer which I've given (Aamir Shah)

Hope the explanation was useful...

Comment: Yeah, I know I could make a custom dialog box, but I don't want to make something overly complicated just for a simple editText.